# Django - Indirect Join Query

Tags: python, django, model

How can I return an indirect joined query that gives me all of the Questions in the Question model.  The caveat, is that for each question, I need to be able to access the UserData model.  The indirect relationship is Question -> User  and User <- UserData (I prefer not to change the model structure if possible).

```
class Question(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    image_url = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)

class Answer(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=16000)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)

class UserData(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    access_token = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    profile_image_url = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

Edit:  I think this relationship is considered a "reverse relationship".

Comment: Can you post some fixtures too ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider [select_related()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related).

From 3 queries, to 2 queries with just select_related(), to 1 query with select_related() given better arguments.

```
In [17]: [q.user.userdata.access_token for q in Question.objects.all()]
DEBUG (0.000) SELECT "testapp_question"."id", "testapp_question"."description", "testapp_question"."pub_date", "testapp_question"."image_url", "testapp_question"."user_id" FROM "testapp_question"; args=()
DEBUG (0.000) SELECT "auth_user"."id", "auth_user"."username", "auth_user"."first_name", "auth_user"."last_name", "auth_user"."email", "auth_user"."password", "auth_user"."is_staff", "auth_user"."is_active", "auth_user"."is_superuser", "auth_user"."last_login", "auth_user"."date_joined" FROM "auth_user" WHERE "auth_user"."id" = 1 ; args=(1,)
DEBUG (0.000) SELECT "testapp_userdata"."id", "testapp_userdata"."user_id", "testapp_userdata"."access_token", "testapp_userdata"."profile_image_url" FROM "testapp_userdata" WHERE "testapp_userdata"."user_id" = 1 ; args=(1,)
Out[17]: [u'1']

In [18]: [q.user.userdata.access_token for q in Question.objects.all().select_related()]
DEBUG (0.000) SELECT "testapp_question"."id", "testapp_question"."description", "testapp_question"."pub_date", "testapp_question"."image_url", "testapp_question"."user_id", "auth_user"."id", "auth_user"."username", "auth_user"."first_name", "auth_user"."last_name", "auth_user"."email", "auth_user"."password", "auth_user"."is_staff", "auth_user"."is_active", "auth_user"."is_superuser", "auth_user"."last_login", "auth_user"."date_joined" FROM "testapp_question" INNER JOIN "auth_user" ON ("testapp_question"."user_id" = "auth_user"."id"); args=()
DEBUG (0.000) SELECT "testapp_userdata"."id", "testapp_userdata"."user_id", "testapp_userdata"."access_token", "testapp_userdata"."profile_image_url" FROM "testapp_userdata" WHERE "testapp_userdata"."user_id" = 1 ; args=(1,)
Out[18]: [u'1']

In [19]: [q.user.userdata.access_token for q in Question.objects.all().select_related('user__userdata')]
DEBUG (0.000) SELECT "testapp_question"."id", "testapp_question"."description", "testapp_question"."pub_date", "testapp_question"."image_url", "testapp_question"."user_id", "auth_user"."id", "auth_user"."username", "auth_user"."first_name", "auth_user"."last_name", "auth_user"."email", "auth_user"."password", "auth_user"."is_staff", "auth_user"."is_active", "auth_user"."is_superuser", "auth_user"."last_login", "auth_user"."date_joined", "testapp_userdata"."id", "testapp_userdata"."user_id", "testapp_userdata"."access_token", "testapp_userdata"."profile_image_url" FROM "testapp_question" INNER JOIN "auth_user" ON ("testapp_question"."user_id" = "auth_user"."id") LEFT OUTER JOIN "testapp_userdata" ON ("auth_user"."id" = "testapp_userdata"."user_id"); args=()
Out[19]: [u'1']
```

It is interresting to note that you don't have to call selected related with `('user', 'user__userdata')`: You can see the last query fetches data from the 3 tables with just '`user__userdata`':

```
SELECT 
    "testapp_question"."id", "testapp_question"."description" [...]
    "auth_user"."id", "auth_user"."username" [...]
    "testapp_userdata"."id", "testapp_userdata"."user_id"  [...]
FROM
    "testapp_question" INNER JOIN 
    "auth_user" ON ("testapp_question"."user_id" = "auth_user"."id") LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    "testapp_userdata" ON ("auth_user"."id" = "testapp_userdata"."user_id")
```

Comment: I read that this does not work with reverse relationships like mine, is that correct?

Comment: The select related does include the reverse relationship because `UserData.user` is a `OneToOneField`. It wouldn't work if it was a foreign key.

Comment: @jpic Side question, how did you get that debug output?

Comment: Sent 'django' logging to 'console' handler which uses 'simple' formatter: http://dpaste.com/706671/ njoy B)

Answer (score 3):

```
Question.objects.select_related('user__userdata').all()
```

will get both the `User` object and the `UserData` object for every question. Reverse relationships aren't supported **except** in `OneToOne` relationships like you have ([As seen here](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/7270))

Comment: Are you sure that related_name='userdata' is useful here?

Comment: No, it's not - sorry I just deleted it from the question before you commented - I forgot it was a OneToOne which doesn't need it